# Time difference in two clocks

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Two identical (and synchronized) clocks C1 & C2, are at same location A. Clock C2 is then moved from location A to another location B which is distance D away from A. Thereafter both the clocks remain at their respective locations, i.e. in same frame of reference.

Q1. As I understand, C1 at A & C2 at B, may give the different time readings, but will the rate of change of time be same in both the clocks? A Yes/No answer will do.

Q2. If the answer to Q1 is Yes then, just because of displacement of clock C2 from point A to point B, what is the equation for the difference in the time between the two clocks. If it depends upon how C2 was moved from A to B, please assume the simplest case because for the purpose of my question, it does not matter how it was moved (slowly, or fast..), so if it helps, you may consider a straight line move from A to B at a constant speed. Obviously, it needs to accelerate from A and then needs to stop at B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Yes. The clocks end up at rest relative to one another and therefore (in flat spacetime) tick at the same rate.

Q2: the time difference *completely* depends on path used. The difference can be made as close to $0$ as you like by moving Clock C2 suitably slowly (but not exactly $0$ and of course never less than $0$). The difference can be made as close to $\infty$ as you like by sending C2 on a near-$c$ joyride for a long time.

For the specific case of Clock C2 moving at constant velocity, covering distance $D$ in time $T,$ the time difference (amount by which C1 is ahead of C2) is $\Delta t=T-\sqrt{T^2-(D/c)^2}$ (draw the spacetime diagram and compare the lengths of paths—thinking explicitly about acceleration is unnecessary). Again, $\Delta t$ can be made as tiny as you want as long as you're willing to move C2 slowly enough: $\lim_{T\to\infty}\Delta t=0.$ The maximum $\Delta t$ achievable with this straight path is however limited to $\Delta t<D/c$ due to the condition $D/T<c,$ since the clock can't travel faster than light.

Comment: Thank you HTNW. I am not interested in making the delta small or large. All I need is a simple case scenario - straight line move at a finite realistic speed say 100 or 1000 miles an hour. I think you answered both my questions. Can you please point me to a reference for the equation for delta t? Thank you very much.

Comment: @kpv I just derived it: If C2 moves distance $D$ in time $T$ at constant velocity while C1 remains at rest, then C1 experiences time $T$ while C2 experiences time $\sqrt{T^2-(D/c)^2}$ (the hypotenuse of a triangle with $+$ leg $T$ and $-$ leg $D/c$). $\Delta t$ is the difference.